# How to 'subtract' overlapping tuple time ranges in two different lists

Tags: python

I have two lists of tuples, each tuple is composed of a start and end time (in seconds from epoch) like so:

```
list1= [(2,4), (7,10), (14,22)]

list2 = [(1,3), (5,8), (9,15), (20,24)]
```

I need to create a new list of tuples (start, end) ranges that removes the time intervals where the tuple from `list2` overlaps with the tuple from `list1`.

The expected output from said method, given `list1` and `list2` would be:

```
[(3,4), (8,10), (15,20)]
```

For what it is worth, both `list1` and `list2` will be comprised of unique time ranges, i.e. there will be no overlap within each respective individual lists.

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: I've tried iterating over both lists, while comparing list2 tuple to see if it overlaps with list1 tuple, then add tuple to a new list and continue to iterate. I have not gotten anywhere that feels like it will pay off, hence the lack of code in the question.

Comment: This feels very homework-ish. I think that a [proper question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) around a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will have much better chances of being answered.

Comment: It's a work related problem. I need to write some test code to verify an alarm aggregation routine, where list1 alarms needs to be ignored while list2 alarms are active. I'll try to re-word, but with the limited amount of useful code I have produced, there isn't much to add in that regard.

Comment: I would like to help, but your explanation is not complete enough for me to understand why the expected output is what it is. Which list are you starting from, and what are you removing? At first I thought you were starting with `list1` and removing ranges from `list2`. But in that case your expected output would not contain `(22,24)`, because there is no range in `list1` that goes up to 24. So it's not at all clear to me what you are trying to produce.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that only iterates once on each element of the lists.

With `list1 = [(2, 4), ...]` and `list2 = [(1, 3), ...]`, we have:

- at 1, start of a deleted part
- at 2, start of an interval
- at 3, end of a deleted part
- at 4, end of an interval

The output is made of the parts where we are both inside an interval and not in a deleted part.

So, the idea is to go through the events in order, keeping track of whether we are in an interval or not, and inside a deleted part or not.

We start by creating a generator from each list, that will generate:

- For the first one, `Event(pos=2, toggle='in_interval')`, `Event(pos=4, toggle='in_interval')` and so on.
- For the second one, `Event(pos=1, toggle='in_deleted')`, `Event(pos=3, toggle='in_deleted')`...

We don't need to care if each value is the start or end of an interval, as it just toggles the state (inside/outside of an interval).

We can then use [heapq.merge](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html#heapq.merge) to get the events in order from these two generators, which will give us something like:

`Event(pos=1, toggle='in_deleted')`, `Event(pos=2, toggle='in_interval')`, `Event(pos=3, toggle='in_deleted')`, `Event(pos=4, toggle='in_interval')`...

Each event will toggle the associated state. We have the start of a new interval for the output when we are both in an interval and not in a deleted part. The rest is self-explanatory...

```
from heapq import merge
from itertools import chain
from collections import namedtuple

def remaining(intervals, deleted):
    Event = namedtuple('Event', ['position', 'toggle'])

    int_iter = (Event(position=pos, toggle='in_interval') for pos in chain.from_iterable(intervals))
    del_iter = (Event(position=pos, toggle='in_deleted') for pos in chain.from_iterable(deleted))

    state = {'in_interval': False, 'in_deleted': False}
    start = None
    out = []

    for event in merge(int_iter, del_iter):
        state[event.toggle] = not state[event.toggle]
        if state['in_interval'] and not state['in_deleted']:
            # start a new interval
            start = event.position
        elif start is not None:
            # end an interval. If it's not empty, we append it to the output
            if event.position > start:
                out.append((start, event.position))
            start = None
    return out
```

Example output:

```
list1 = [(2,4), (7,10), (14,22)]
list2 = [(1,3), (5,8), (9,15), (20,24)]      

print(remaining(list1, list2))
# [(3, 4), (8, 9), (15, 20)]
```